# webdrive click an element in a list when the class does not reference the name

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I am doing a search, and then attempting to click on the name returned from the search result
If i do a search for Bond, the below is the result I will see on the page

```
    <li class = "resultsItem  " data-index ="0">
    <div class = "name" data-cid ="d182a061-1afd-4924-b256-035d7e6f34ec" onclick="return true;">
    Bond, James      </div>
    <a class = "ir icon emailAction" href="mailto:jamesbond@mi6@.com"1</a>
    </li>
```

I tried using the following with selenium webdriver in Ruby

```
    element = driver.find_element(:name, "Bond, James")
    element = driver.find_element(:text, "Bond, James")
    element = driver.find_element(:data-cid, "d182a061-1afd-4924-b256-035d7e6f34ec")
```

I didn't think name, or text would work.  I didn't like data-cid but was hoping that would work.
Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,

Jeff

Comment: After a bit more fiddling around, I found the answer

        element = driver.find_elements (:xpath, "//li @class='resultsItem   ']/div")
        for item in element
            if item.text() == "Bond, James" then
                item.click
            end
        end

Hope this helps anyone else that runs into this :)

Comment: Have a look on this : http://selenium.polteq.com/en/injecting-the-sizzle-css-selector-library/

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with it for ahwile, I was able to get things working with the code blow

```
element = driver.find_elements (:xpath, "//li @class='resultsItem ']/div") 
for item in element 
 if item.text() == "Bond, James" then 
  item.click 
 end 
end
```

Thanks,

Jeff